# How to remove network self loops MATLAB

Tags: matlab, networking, matrix

I have a file where there is a huge matrix (10903x3) forming a network with duplicated nodes and self-loops.

I want to get the `Laplacian matrix` and for that first I compute the graph of the network.

The steps I follow are:

- Remove duplicated nodes using this code (it works):

  Au = unique( [ sort( A(:,[1,2]), 2 ) A(:,3)], 'rows' );
- Then I calculate Laplacian matrix by*:

  L = laplacian(Au)

  *but it can not be computed since there are some self-loops and the network is so big I do not know how to find and remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the graph and digraph classes, you can use the option 'OmitSelfLoops' when you create the graph.

Otherwise, self loops appear as nonzero elements on the diagonal of the adjacency matrix. So you can construct the adjacency matrix and zero out the diagonal to remove the self loops.